# Chronometer too fast

Tags: genexus

I have a [Chronometer Control](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?25058,Chronometer%20Control) in a web page created in C# with Genexus 17U4.

It works fine most of time, but randomly and rarely it slows down or accelerates a lot. If I reload the page, the control start counting correctly again. I have WWP on the panel it this matters.

Anyone know what could cause this behavior?

Comment: I made some tests and couldn't see the error you mention. Could you please contact gx support with a working example / xpz?